# One scroll Up / One scroll Down

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

```js
sections=$("section");
s=0;

$(".next").click(function() {
 if(s<sections.length-1){
 s++;
 $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: sections.eq(s).offset().top
 }, 500);
}});

$(".previous").click(function() {
if(s>0){
 s--;
 $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: sections.eq(s).offset().top
 }, 500);
}});
```

```css
section{
  min-height:100vh;
}
#arrow{
    position:fixed;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<section id="about">About Us</section>
<section id="clients">Clients</section>
<section id="workwithus">Work With Us</section>
<section id="contact">Contact US</section>
<div id="arrow">
  <a class="next">next</a>
  <a class="previous">prev</a>
</div>
```

I want to link the page sections to my scroll event, if I scroll Up for one time, one section should go up, similarly if I scroll Down for one time, one section should come down, I've done by on click event which is working fine, but i want that to implemented on scroll + arrow up and down too.

Comment: That's cool. So what's the problem? Are you familiar with [`keypress`](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/)?

Comment: scroll part I cannot implement

Comment: So read about `keypress` and search for "jquery mousewheel". The whole process is very, very similar to your click handlers.